# « Jeter les feux » : vocabulaire professionnel ou usuel ?

Tags: histoire, terminologie, synonymes, france, transports

> Faites jeter les feux !

Dans une scène du film [*La Bataille du rail*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Bataille_du_rail) (René Clément, 1946), on entend quelqu'un dire à ces valeureux cheminots (de la [SNCF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_nationale_des_chemins_de_fer_fran%C3%A7ais) vraisemblablement) : « *Ordre de la résistance : Faites jeter les feux* ». On avait réussi à faire interrompre le courant des locomotives électriques mais l'occupant ordonnât aussitôt la remise en service d'éléments du parc ferroviaire à vapeur, que par ce genre de manœuvre on s'affaire ainsi de retarder. Il s'agit d'un enjeu crucial alors que le chemin de fer est essentiel à l'approvisionnement et au transport des troupes et équipements de l'armée d'occupation pendant la Seconde Guerre mondiale et que le débarquement semble imminent.

[image]

<sup>Dans le film *La Bataille du rail* (1946) de René Clément, un chauffeur tire sur un levier dans la locomotive et le charbon, dont partie est incandescente, tombe sur les rails ; puis on a la lueur sous les [locomotives](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locomotives_%C3%A0_vapeur_fran%C3%A7aises) dans la nuit...</sup>

---

- De quel sens de [*jeter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jeter) s'agit-il ici (si on estimait qu'il ne s'agit pas du sens usuel) ? Peut-on reformuler avec
  un verbe qui lui est synonyme et qui explique son sens ?
- Quant à l'emploi des *[feu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/feu)x* au pluriel, pourquoi ? Y a-t-il un lien à faire avec *jeter son feu* (dégager de la chaleur), *jeter du feu* (briller vivement) au singulier ? Est-ce toujours du jargon de chemin de fer, ou industriel ; est-ce devenu [*jeter le feu du foyer*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18077529) et pourquoi le cas échéant ?

---

En résumé *jeter les feux* est-il faussement usuel, référant très exactement à un mécanisme et à un combustible particulier ; a-t-on une source crédible à ce sujet ? Ou a-t-on déjà parlé de *jeter les feux* à l'extérieur du cadre ferroviaire, à l'extérieur de celui de la machine à vapeur, antérieurement, de sorte qu'on trouverait usuel aujourd'hui de l'entendre dire au sujet de ce qui se trouve dans un appareil de cuisson à feu vif mobile, par exemple ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Jeter le feu » en langage des cheminots veut dire mettre la machine à l'arrêt complet. Dans cette expression « jeter » est employé au sens propre. Les cheminots ouvraient la *grille jette feu* (c'est son nom) sur laquelle reposaient les braises incandescentes (le feu) et ces braises tombaient sur la voie.

Ces feux étaient jetés lors d'entretiens réguliers ou lors d'incidents particuliers, cas dans *La bataille du rail* où le but était de mettre les locos hors service le plus longtemps possible pour empêcher les Allemands de s'en servir. Une fois le feu jeté il fallait plusieurs heures pour refaire ce feu et remettre la loco en service. Cette technique a été très employée par les cheminots résistants.

> 1943, 25 novembre.- [...]
>   Au dépôt SNCF d'Arras, la conduite principale alimentant les réservoirs d'eau à été détruite, le dépôt a été privé d'eau 56 heures. On a dû jeter le feu de 5 locos. Tous les trains pour Arras ont eu de gros retards 1659 .
>   Extrait de [résistance dans le Pas-de-Calais](http://www.resistance62.net/Chronologie%20resistance%20provisoire.pdf)
>    http://www.resistance62.net/Chronologie.htm.

L'ordre de la résistance est « Faites jeter les feux » parce que chaque locomotive à vapeur avait son feu, il est logique donc de mettre le pluriel. De même on dirait « arrêtez **les machines** » pour parler de machines électriques ou à fuel, « arrêtez la machine » pour une seule machine.

Pour voir de près à quoi ressemblait [une grille jette feu lors d'un entretien](http://www.forum-train.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3770&start=230).

Je ne crois pas que l'expression s'utilise  en dehors des machines à vapeur. Je n'emploierais ici le terme de jargon que dans le sens de « vocabulaire professionnel ».

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Faut fréquenter les forums de cheminots. En France les amateurs de locomotives à vapeurs sont nombreux (forums, petits trains du dimanche qu'on astique et sort les jours de fêtes...) et pas que chez les cheminots. Il n'y a peut-être pas cette culture où tu vis. T'es Québécois(e), non? (je ne sais pas pourquoi je me suis fait cet idée)

Comment: @ɑ̃sakʁamɑ̃ Eh! les trains touristiques du dimanche et jours de fêtes c'est pas des modèles réduits ! Ce sont des vieux bichonnés avec soin. Et faut voir en Angleterre, là c'est pire qu'en France, de vrais amoureux. Pour moi pas de doute sur le pluriel. Voir les forums de cheminots. Chaque machine a son feu.

Answer (score 1):

Pour compléter la réponse détaillée de Laure, « jeter les feux » n'est plus du tout employé aujourd'hui (il n'y a plus de locomotives à vapeur depuis longtemps) et ne serait pas compris en dehors d'un contexte bien particulier comme celui du film de René Clément.

Comment: Tout à fait compris des amateurs de locomotives à vapeur aussi !